# Force TFS to get latest prior to check in

Tags: tfs

In tfs options you can set tfs to locally get latest item on check-out. Is there anyway to force get latest prior to check in to avoid overwrites? I'm not TFS admin btw.

Comment: There is always chances of overwrites if you don't take care.. Even if you force to get latest prior to check in or get latest after check in. So the real solution might not be to force get latest but to learn/teach how to merge while checking in or while getting latest

Comment: We are not using branches in the environment I'm working in-everything gets checked in and out of the main trunk. Branches would help out a lot.

Comment: I also work on TFS which is one main branch.. and around 12 developers are working on it, All I had to do was to teach them what happens during get latest (before or after checkin) and why they get merge conflicts and how to resolve it. Also I feel its better to get latest prior to checkin,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think which you want is to "get latest get the latest" and avoid TFS force you to resolve conflicts before checking in.

However, TFS redefined what "Get Latest" does. In TFS terms, Get Latest means **get the latest version of the files, but ignore the ones that the server thinks is already in your workspace.**  Moreover, **doing a get latest is good practice, but not mandatory.** There is no such settings.

There has been some similar questions in SO and got an amazing answer, below links for your reference:

- [Is performing a Get Latest mandatory before checking in in TFS so you do not overwrite/lose code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062577/is-performing-a-get-latest-mandatory-before-checking-in-in-tfs-so-you-do-not-ove)
- [Why doesn't TFS get latest get the latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest)