# TFS 2015 - How do I ensure daily forward and reverse integrations?

Tags: tfs

My development team is using TFS for source control.  My current plan is to have a new shared branch created each sprint for the developers to use for all their tasks.

What is the best way to ensure that the developers are performing forward and reverse integration every day for that branch?  In other words, how do I make sure they are constantly getting the latest code set from the sprint branch and checking their code in as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such VS extension can force developers to get code from TFS and check in frequently and continuously.

If which you want is to "get the latest " and avoid TFS force you/colleagues to resolve conflicts before checking in.

However, TFS redefined what "Get Latest" does. In TFS terms, Get Latest means **get the latest version of the files, but ignore the ones that the server thinks is already in your workspace.**  Moreover, **doing a get latest is good practice, but not mandatory.** There is no such settings.

There has been some similar questions in SO and got an amazing answer, below links for your reference:

- [Is performing a Get Latest mandatory before checking in in TFS so you do not overwrite/lose code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062577/is-performing-a-get-latest-mandatory-before-checking-in-in-tfs-so-you-do-not-ove)
- [Why doesn't TFS get latest get the latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest)

As a workaround, if you really need this feature in your team, you could set up a reminder such as meeting reminder in outlook 4:00PM to  remind your colleagues, they should merge their work in the branch at the end of day. Just couldn't force them to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a people problem, not a tooling problem. There's no way the tool can force their behavior when it comes to committing their code or merging branches. It's just part of workflow discipline, which will come with time.